# Axios POST Request to Backend '/user/signup' Endpoint Results in Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, axios, mern

I'm encountering an Internal Server Error (HTTP 500) when making an Axios POST request to the '/user/signup' endpoint in my web application. This issue is bit hard to find, and I'm seeking guidance to understand and resolve it.
When attempting to sign up a user through the Axios POST request, the backend server returns a 500 Internal Server Error. This error message doesn't provide specific details about the problem, making it challenging to pinpoint the root cause.

```js
// auth.js

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (isSignup){
        dispatch(signupauth(formData,navigate))
        console.log("user in the sign up received form data",formData)
        
    } else {
      dispatch(signinauth(formData,navigate))

    }


    console.log(formData)

  }
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})

  }
```

Here how i configured the api using axios, i'm getting error here

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const API = axios.create({baseURL : 'http://localhost:5000'})

// const url = 'http://localhost:5000/posts';


export const fetchPosts = () => API.get('/posts');
export const createPost = (newPost) => API.post('/posts',newPost);
export const updatePost = (id,updatedPost) => API.patch(`/posts/${id}`,updatedPost)
export const deletePost = (id) => API.delete(`/posts/${id}`)
export const likePost = (id) => API.patch(`/posts/${id}/likePost`)


export const signIn = (formData) => API.post('/user/signin',formData)

export const signUp = (formData) => API.post('/user/signup',formData) // in console it showing error here

// reducers_auth.js

const initialState = {
    authData: null,
};

const authSlice1 = createSlice({
    name: 'auth1',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        reducers: {
            signin: (state, action) => {
                state.authData = action.payload;
                localStorage.setItem('authToken', JSON.stringify(action.payload)); // Store token in localStorage
            },
            signup: (state, action) => {
                state.authData = action.payload;
                localStorage.setItem('authToken', JSON.stringify(action.payload)); // Store token in localStorage
            },
        }
    }



})

export const { signin, signup } = authSlice1.actions;
export default authSlice1.reducer;


export const signinauth = createAsyncThunk('/user/signin', async ({ formData, navigate }, { dispatch }) => {
    try {

        const { data } = await signIn(formData);
        console.log("your are inside singin auth", data);
        dispatch(signin(data));
        navigate('/')



    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error.message);
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
});

export const signupauth = createAsyncThunk('/user/signup', async ({ formData, navigate }, { dispatch }) => {
    try {


        const { data } = await signUp(formData);
        console.log("your inside redudcers of signupauth", data);
        dispatch(signup(data));
        // navigate('/')



    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error.message);
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
});
```

Backend code provided below, request isn't reaching backend. It's struck near axios api config.

```js
export const signin = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!existingUser) return res.status(404).json({ message: "User doesn't exist with provided email id" });

        const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(password, existingUser.password);

        if (!isPasswordCorrect) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid Credentials' });

        const token = jwt.sign({ email: existingUser.email, id: existingUser._id }, 'test', { expiresIn: '1h' });

        res.status(200).json({ result: existingUser, token });
        console.log(token);
        // Continue with the rest of your code here
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors that occurred during the database query
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
};

export const signup = async (req, res) => {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmpassword } = req.body;
    console.log("ok it won't work")
    try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (existingUser) return res.status(403).json({ message: "User Already Exists" });

        if (password !== confirmpassword) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Passwords are not the same. Please check!!!' });

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

        const result = await User.create({ email, password: hashedPassword, name: `${firstName} ${lastName}` });

        const token = jwt.sign({ email: result.email, id: result._id }, 'test', { expiresIn: '1h' });

        res.status(200).json({ result, token });
        console.log(token, 'is from backend of controllers/users');
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors that occurred during the database query
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
};
```

```js
import express from 'express'
import { signin,signup } from '../controllers/users.js';

const router = express.Router();


router.post('/signin',signin)
router.post('/signup',signup)


export default router


// router config

import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js'
import userRoutes from './routes/user.js'

const app = express();
dotenv.config()




app.use(bodyParser.json({limit : "30mb", extended : true}))
// excepts the incoming http request i.e client sends the request to server, and it verifies it 
// limit is 30mb and extended is true enables nested parsing 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit : "30mb", extended : true}))
app.use(cors());
app.use('/posts',postRoutes)
app.use('/user', userRoutes)


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL)
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`)))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message) )

// mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)
```

export const signUp = (formData) => API.post('/user/signup',formData) // error showing for this line of code

POST http://localhost:5000/user/signup 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: _"This error message doesn't provide specific details about the problem"_ - it's not _supposed to_, because you would not want to expose potentially critical internal details of how your site works, to just any random visitor that encountered a 500. _"making it challenging to pinpoint the root cause"_ - as we are saying here all. the. time - when you get a 500, then your first look should be into the actual _error logs_ of the application that threw that error.

Comment: I have checked error log from backend, in backend i'm not receiving data, infact the request is not reaching redux thunk, "export const signUp = (formData) => API.post('/user/signup',formData)" all errors showing here and this is the error from backend server "{} body of request Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, number"

Comment: `undefined, number` suggest you are probably not sending, what you think you were. I doubt the first value is _supposed_ to be `undefined`. So have you checked what you are actually sending, on the client side yet?

Comment: // reducers_auth.js in the code mentioned above, i'm not  receiving the data here, but from form i'm sending it and In reducers i'm not getting it.

Comment: _"but from form i'm sending it"_ - do you _think_ you are sending it, or have you _verified_ that you are sending it? Check the actual request that is made, using your browser dev tools.

Comment: `if (isSignup){
      console.log('Dispatching signupauth with formData:', formData);`
i can view in the browser
`console.log("receive data",formData)
  const { data } = await signUpAPi(formData);
  console.log("Inside signupauth async thunk", data);
 dispatch(signup(data));`

Comment: yes i verified it in console. thanks figure it out before 
`dispatch(signupauth(formData,navigate))` after `dispatch(signupauth({formData,navigate}))`

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (isSignup){
      console.log('Dispatching signupauth with formData:', formData);
      // before dispatch(signupauth(formData,navigate))
        dispatch(signupauth({formData,navigate}))
        console.log("user in the sign up received form data",formData)
        
    } else {
      dispatch(signinauth({formData,navigate}))

    }
// this resolved internal server error.
```